# MySQL insert if rows exist in temporary table

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a row into my table if there are 1 or more records in my temporary table *temp*. Usually it's the other way around where i'd want to update if the row exists, and insert otherwise. So how would i solve this? It doesn't seem like there is a *if exists* statement i could use, and a quick search shows me that *INSERT INTO* doesn't support the *where*-clause.

Comment: I think, you'll have to create a stored procedure to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`insert into` definitely does support a `where` clause.  You just have to use the `insert into . . . select` form of it:

```
insert into mytable(<whatever>)
    select <whatever>
    from (select count(*) as cnt from temp) c
    where c.cnt > 0;
```

Okay, technically the `where` clause is part of the `select`, but it does what you want.

MySQL does not support `where` clause without a `from` clause.  This solves that problem by using the `from` clause to calculate the count in the temp table.  If the count is greater than 0 (or whatever number you want), then it inserts the row.

Comment: That's a great and well working solution! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Like [@Gordon Linoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16760472/297408), the following is based on the same idea of using `INSERT...SELECT` instead of `INSERT...VALUES`, because the former allows one to throw in a WHERE condition. However, I would approach the problem of getting around the limitation of WHERE without FROM differently:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (list_of_columns)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT list_of_values) s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM temp_table)
;
```

If the temporary table may hold many rows, this might perform better than Gordon's suggestion, because `EXISTS (SELECT * ...)` doesn't need to scan the entire table when there's at least one row that matches the subquery, while `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` would need to count all the rows every time.

If there can't be many rows in the temporary table, the advantage, if any, would likely be unnoticeable.